# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Realm on disk is newer than the one specified: v3 vs. v0?

Tags: android, realm

How to solve this issue, i searched for result i dont't know how to solve the result.

I am using broadcast receiver to receive data

```
   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Realm.init(context);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}
```

In broadcast receiver class i have initialized the realm. The issue is occurring at line ` realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();. Please help me how to solve this.

The realm initializaion in oncreate() method of the application is

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        Realm.init(this);
//        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
//                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
//                .build();
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(3) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
                .migration(new Migration()) // Migration to run
                .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
//        Realm.deleteRealm(config);
        realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

I have initialized the realm in the activity.Please help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Realm.init(context);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

to

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Realm.init(context);
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
            .migration(new Migration()) // Migration to run
            .build();
    realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

in your broadcast receiver.

And

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(SCHEMA_VERSION) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
            .migration(new Migration()) // Migration to run
            .build();
```

Move `SCHEMA_VERSION` property somewhere where it's a `public static final int` (constant).

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `Realm.setDefaultInstance(config)` was not set when your broadcast receiver was triggered.

It looks like you are setting the default configuration in an activity. You should do so in `Application.onCreate()` instead.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .schemaVersion(3) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
                .migration(new Migration()) // Migration to run
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }
}

// Remember to set `name` in Manifest as well
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.realm.examples.intro" >
    <application android:name=".MyApplication">
        <!-- Activities -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: In your answer , i have to create the separate activity that should extend my application

Comment: i am little confused what is "MyApplication" and "Application" in your answer

Comment: Setting a default configuration in `Realm.init()` strikes again :P

Comment: `Application` is provided by Android, `MyApplication` is a class you create.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, not really. Trying to setup everything inside the activity would have failed for the BroadcastReceiver, no matter how the API looked :)